# Symfony2 translation returns only english

Tags: symfony

I am trying to get along with translation service in symfony2. The problem I am facing is that this code always returns the english version of the key

```
$translator = $this->get('translator');
$translator->setlocale('fr'); // locale gets ignored
die($translator->trans('pisica')); //always outputs cat altough the translation in french exists too.
```

I would like to specify in controller witch locale I am using because it is best for what I am trying to acomplish

Comment: Did you check out http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#handling-the-user-s-locale - according to that you should set before you're doing anything else, you might to call it too late.

Comment: you can also define the locale directly `$translator->trans('pisica',   array(),   'translation_domain', 'fr');`

Answer (score 0):

Set the Locale in the Request object, not in the translator service.
$request->setLocale('fr');

$translator->trans('something');